# How to freeze the first 10 layers in the TFHub model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

I am trying to make the first 10 layers in this TFHub model to be non-traininable. I want to freeze those layers so that I can finetune the remaining layers. I could not find any example to do this. I have seen similar examples in Keras models such as resNet50 where layers.trainable can be exclusively set to True or False. I am not able to do this in TFHub models. Any pointer will be appreciated. Thanks

```
import tensorflow_hub as tfhub

model_loc = "https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v1_50/classification/5"
model = tfhub.KerasLayer(
    model_loc,
    input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
    trainable=True)
```

Comment: check this - [tf hub transfer learning](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning_with_hub#simple_transfer_learning)

Comment: @ahmedshahriar, That page only says how to freeze the entire model or unfreeze the entire model. I am looking to unfreeze only few layers and not all the layers. Please see my OP.

Comment: I suggest create a github issue then, sorry can't help you more